# application.getContext() returns null when context path is ''

Tags: java, apache, jsp, tomcat

I am currently running a Java web application on Tomcat 6, and have set up a virtual host in Apache HTTP Server to forward requests to the Tomcat. The context paths are therefore different. When the web app is accessed at

```
http://server:8080/WebApp
```

the context path is '/WebApp' and the context is retrieved. When accessing the same JSP via the proxy at

```
http://webapp/
```

the context path is '' and application.getContext() returns null.

Is there any configuration I might have missed when setting up the virtual host, or is this a problem with the application code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no point in calling

```
application.getContext(application.getContextPath())
```

The `getContext` method is for getting a reference to the `ServletContext` for a *different* web application (and the container is allowed by the spec to return `null` if the current app does not have permission to access other contexts - this is the default in Tomcat unless you've specified `crossContext="true"` in the context configuration file).

You already have a reference to the `ServletContext` for the current webapp - in the `application` variable.